# I'm trying to play audio through earpiece on Android device (Huawei), but no sound output, I have tried lots of methods

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I have tried three methods, codes are showed below.

In method one, `AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` is used.

```
// method one
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("signal.wav");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                          fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), 
                          fileDescriptor.getLength());

audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                             audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 
                             AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK);

mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

In method two, AudioAttributes is used with AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH and AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION.

```
// method two
AudioAttributes mAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
                .build();

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("signal.wav");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                          fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), 
                          fileDescriptor.getLength());

mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

In method three, `ExoPlayer` is used to play audio, the setting is a little like method two, maybe you can ignore this method.

```
// method three
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("//android_asset/signal.wav"));

SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "MyCamera"));
MediaSource Source = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);

player.prepare(Source);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

player.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(earpiece ? C.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH : C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .setUsage(earpiece ? C.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION : C.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .build());
```

By the way, I does set the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Those methods seem to work well for others, I am not sure if it was the Phone, I hope someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it works well with another phone, I think there may be some faults on the original phone.

Answer (score 0):

First ,it is recommended to plug in other mobile phones first to try whether there is sound.
Second, if other mobile phones are available, try plugging in the headset again and rotating the headset properly. If it still fails, the headset may be damaged. It is recommended to replace the headset
Method three,   if the earphone used is not the original earphone,it may also be because the earphone is not compatible. Try replacing the Original earphone and try.
Method five,
  Enter the developer option to see if the USB audio switch is turned off. If it is turned on, just turn it off

Settings - systems and updates - Developer options

Method 6,

If the developer option is not found in the system update

In settings - System - about mobile phone, click version number 7 times in a row - until you are prompted that you are in developer mode

Then return to the system and repeat step 4
Method 7.
Check whether the earphone hole is blocked. If yes, clean the foreign matters